# Is there a performance difference between `select` and `select!` when called on a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, performance, sorting, hash

```
hash = { 'mark' => 1, 'jane' => 1, 'peter' => 35 }.select {|k,v| v > 1}
#=> { 'peter' => 35 }
```

What if I have millions of keys - is there a difference between

`hash = hash.select` vs `hash.select!` ?

Comment: Why don't you run a simple benchmark yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select!` will perform better (I'll show the source for MRI, but it should be the same for the others).

The reason for this is that [`select`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1397) needs to [create a whole new `Hash` object](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1402), and will, [for each entry in the hash](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1404), [copy the entry](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1377) - [if the block succeeds](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1376).

On the other hand, [`select!`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1428), will, [for each key](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1460), [remove the value](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1413) - [if the block doesn't succeed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1412) - [in-place](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L338) (with no need for new object creation).

Answer (score 7):

You can always do a little benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

# Creates a big hash in the format: { 1 => 1, 2 => 2 ... }
big_hash = 100_000.times.inject({}) { |hash, i| hash.tap { |h| h[i] = i }   }
Benchmark.bm do |bm|
   bm.report('select') { big_hash.select{ |k,v| v > 50 } }
   bm.report('select!') { big_hash.select!{ |k,v| v > 50 } }
end

         user       system     total     real
select   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000  (  0.088048)
select!  0.020000   0.000000   0.020000  (  0.021324)
```

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely yes. `select!` is in-place and leads to fewer GC sweeps and less consumption of memory. As proof of concept:

This is ./wrapper.rb:

```
require 'json'
require 'benchmark'

def measure(&block)
  no_gc = ARGV[0] == '--no-gc'

  no_gc ? GC.disable : GC.start

  memory_before = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_f #/ 1024
  gc_stat_before = GC.stat
  time = Benchmark.realtime do
    yield
  end
  puts ObjectSpace.count_objects
  if !no_gc
    puts "  Sweeping"
    GC.start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true, immediate_mark: false)
  end
  puts ObjectSpace.count_objects
  gc_stat_after = GC.stat
  memory_after = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_f # / 1024
  puts({
    RUBY_VERSION => {
      gc: no_gc ? 'disabled': 'enabled',
      time: time.round(2),
      gc_count: gc_stat_after[:count] - gc_stat_before[:count],
      memory: "%d MB" % (memory_after - memory_before)
    }
  }.to_json)
  puts "---------\n"
end
```

This is ./so_question.rb:

```
require_relative './wrapper'
data = Array.new(100) { ["x","y"].sample * 1024 * 1024 }

measure do
  data.select! { |x| x.start_with?("x") }
end
measure do
  data = data.select { |x| x.start_with?("x") }
end
```

Running it:

```
ruby so_question.rb --no-gc
```

Results in:

```
{:TOTAL=>30160, :FREE=>21134, :T_OBJECT=>160, :T_CLASS=>557,
:T_MODULE=>38, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>5884, :T_REGEXP=>75,
:T_ARRAY=>710, :T_HASH=>35, :T_STRUCT=>2, :T_BIGNUM=>2, :T_FILE=>3,
:T_DATA=>896, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>618, :T_ICLASS=>38}   
{:TOTAL=>30160, :FREE=>21067, :T_OBJECT=>160, :T_CLASS=>557,
:T_MODULE=>38, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>5947, :T_REGEXP=>75,
:T_ARRAY=>710, :T_HASH=>38, :T_STRUCT=>2, :T_BIGNUM=>2, :T_FILE=>3,
:T_DATA=>897, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>618, :T_ICLASS=>38}   
{"2.2.2":{"gc":"disabled","time":0.0,"gc_count":0,"memory":"20 MB"}}   

{:TOTAL=>30160, :FREE=>20922, :T_OBJECT=>162, :T_CLASS=>557, :T_MODULE=>38, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>6072, :T_REGEXP=>75,
:T_ARRAY=>717, :T_HASH=>45, :T_STRUCT=>2, :T_BIGNUM=>2, :T_FILE=>3,
:T_DATA=>901, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>618, :T_ICLASS=>38}   
{:TOTAL=>30160, :FREE=>20885, :T_OBJECT=>162, :T_CLASS=>557,
:T_MODULE=>38, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>6108, :T_REGEXP=>75,
:T_ARRAY=>717, :T_HASH=>46, :T_STRUCT=>2, :T_BIGNUM=>2, :T_FILE=>3,
:T_DATA=>901, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>618, :T_ICLASS=>38}    
{"2.2.2":{"gc":"disabled","time":0.0,"gc_count":0,"memory":"0 MB"}}
```

Note the memory difference. Also, I made this example with Array instead of Hash, but both will behave in the same way because `#select` is an enumerator.